# Change text displayed below app icon on android/eclipse

Tags: android, title

I would like to change the text that is displayed below the icon when you can look at all the apps on your phone, i.e. the "Facebook" below the facebook logo icon. How would I go about doing this? I have tried strings.xml but that did not have what I was looking for. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it programmatically in your activity:

```
setTitle("Activity title");
```

or

```
getActionBar().setTitle("Activity title");
```

Or in your AndroidManifest file, there is `android:label` tag:

```
   <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"            
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity
                android:name="com.example.so1.MainActivity"
                android:label="ACTIVITY NAME"
                >

            </activity>
        </application>
```

Also if you want to change Launcher activity's title to something different than your app name then you could do it like this:

```
<application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"            
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity
                android:name="com.example.so1.MainActivity"
                android:label="ACTIVITY NAME"
                >
                <intent-filter android:label="APP NAME">
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>
```

Answer (score 1):

> How would I go about doing this?

This is controlled by [the `android:label` attribute on the `<activity>` element in the manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#label) for your `LAUNCHER` activity. If your `<activity>` does not have an `android:label` attribute, it will inherit the value from the `<application>` element.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it for your app that you are building,, then you need to change it in`AndroidManifest.xml` under `android:label`

```
<application
    android:label="@string/app_name"
```

In your `string.xml` you can have an entry with `app_name`.

```
<string name="app_name">The Name</string>
```

Hope it helps.